# Advanced Sass package for SublimeText 2

Tags: sass, sublimetext2

is there a Sass Package for ST2 with an enhanced support for nested selectors? The one i installed via package control doesn't handle the code folding right. It doesn't show code folding when using selectors with just one declaration (for normal css files ST2 doesn't show code folding when there is only one declaration too) and when using selectors like "& >".

Here is a screenshot of what i mean:

[image: screenshot]

I can't fold "& > header" and "h1". I'm doing something wrong or don't understand some fundamental things?

Mario

Comment: Just so you know, you don't actually need an `&` in those instances.  These have the same result:  `body { > .foo {} }` and `body { & > .foo {} }`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that doesn't change ST2's behavior. ;)

Comment: Sorry for not answering, but what's that color scheme you are using?

Comment: Hey Petr, this is Tomorrow-Night.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Sass for TextMate/Sublime Text 2](https://github.com/mischah/Sublime-Text-2-Settings/tree/master/Sass) and it performs the folding that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tadiou! Right now package control didn't shows this package (only another with the "same" name. I'll try to install it manually.